# How to solve 2 variable and it must satisfy with 3 equation?

Tags: exponential-function, systems-of-equations

I've been trying to solve equation system, and this is my further question from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2511601/is-there-any-way-to-solve-system-of-differential-equation-for-more-than-10-varia) question befure,
[image]

1. $\Large\frac{9+9}{R_6+R_9}+\frac{9-V_d}{R_4}+\frac{9-V_c}{R_1}=0$
2. $\Large\frac{V_d-9}{R_4}+\frac{V_d-V_c}{R_8}+\frac{V_d}{R_5}+\frac{V_d-V_d⋅{(1-e^{-\frac t{R_7⋅C_2}})}}{R_7}=0$
3. $\Large\frac{V_c-9}{R_1}+\frac{V_c-V_d}{R_8}+\frac{V_c}{R_2}+\frac{V_c-V_c⋅{(1-e^{-\frac t{R_3⋅C_1}})}}{R_3}=0$

I've been trying to use microsoft mathematics, but it force me to solve 3 variable instead of only two, I just only want to solve the $V$'s, the $R$'s are constant.

How do I solve it, in order to satisfy with the three equation?

Comment: Isn't $V_a$ a variable along with $V_c$ and $V_d$? I see three variables.

Comment: @learning it's typo, $V_a$ is known

Comment: Can you post a figure of the circuit?

Comment: Well, pick two equations, solve the system with two variables and two equations and plug your solutions in the third one to check they're correct.

Comment: @Unknown123 Well, I was hoping to see if the equations have been written down correctly. I have forgotten the theory at this stage unfortunately, haha. I do question why you don't have any equation containing $V_b$, but I do see there's a switch.

Comment: @learning Actually I have just realized that the value of $V_b$ before the switch closed is meaningless, if I try to cut the wire between $V2$ and node $a$ and see the graph before and after, it won't alter $V_c$ and $V_d$. so it is meaningless. Even after the switch is closed, $V_b$ and $V_c$ are the same thing haha

Comment: @Lærne some strange things happened, After plugging in the $R$'s value, If I calculate it using microsoft mathematics to solve the equation 2 and 3, I got the correct graph, but if i try to solve the equation 2 with 1, or 3 with 1, I got the wrong graph, what's wrong?

Comment: @learning Sorry, the current flow of $V2$ did alter the $V_c$ and $V_d$ , but for a tiny amount

Comment: I really think you'll be better off asking this on electrical engineering stack exchange. https://electronics.stackexchange.com

Comment: Done, thank you very much for your help, https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/338908/nodal-analysis-solving-2-variables-with-3-equations